# Make background HDRI unsharp

Tags: hdri

I want to present some office products(like folders and binders) on a desk and with a office background, while the background should be unsharp on the renderings.

Should I use HDRI images or set up a interior scene?

Comment: You can use an HDR environment to light the scene and blur the background image. Please read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48240/how-to-make-hdri-map-more-subtle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should prefer using an HDRI in this case for the background. Cycles is a bit sensitive to interior render scenes in terms of noise and therefore high render times. Only build a complete environment if you have very good reasons for it. In your case, all you need is the table as an object, the rest you're better off with a HDRI background.

You can create the blur effect via various methods, I personally find it most convenient to see the result while preview rendering already. If you plan on using Depth of Field in the camera, that would blur the background automatically already. If not, you can create a low res HDRI which is blurrend in an image editor of your choice, and use a node setup like this:

[image: blurred BG]

Plug the blurred version in the bottom image node, and the high res one in the top one. This way reflections on your object will be sharp, but the background will be blurred.

Comment: Is this a Compositing or an Object/Shader related Node setup? I cannot find these nodes in the Compositing Nodes

Comment: @MicroMachine You'll find those nodes in the World Material node tree. So switch to Shader Node Tree setup, and from there choose 'World' instead of 'Material'

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to use a different, second HDRI, you can use this SetUp to blur the vectors of the Hdri with a Noise texture.

[image]