# Making a HDRI map more subtle creates a drop shadow

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, hdri

I tried following cegaton's answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48240/how-to-make-hdri-map-more-subtle/48265?noredirect=1#comment157004_48265) to make a HDRI map more subtle, and the result produced generates a darker edge / drop shadow between the 3D objects and the background:

[image]

I am not sure what causes it.

Comment: can you add an image of your compositing nodes?

Comment: It's because you're blurring the Environment pass.  The environment is ***not*** inclusive of the area behind the building.  In other words, there's a black hole where the building is and you're trying to blur it... therefore some of the blue is going to be darker around the edge.  If you want to blur the environment, it would be better to use layers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you're blurring the ***Environment Pass***. The Environment Pass is ***not inclusive*** of the area behind the building. In other words, there's a black hole where the building is that's being blurred... therefore some of the blue is going to be darker around the edge.

[image]

---

I've been hoping and waiting for the Blender devs to include the capability of making ***only specific layers*** transparent.  As far as I know, this doesn't exist yet.

If you want to blur the environment without having a halo and without having to save a separate render to disk and then composite the image to your scene, you can use the "Glass Sphere" trick.

1.) Set **Transparent** under **Render Properties >> Film**:

[image]

---

2.) Add a **Sphere** object (low poly) with **Smooth Shading** enabled and set the material to be **Glass** with a **IOR of 1.0** and a **Color of 1.0 White**.  Make it large enough to encompass your Camera and then **Parent** it to the Camera:

[image]

---

3.) Create two render layers... one for your setting and one for the sphere.  ***Exclude*** the Sphere's layer from everything else (this ensures that the sphere itself doesn't affect the lighting on any objects in your scene).  Set the ***Number of Samples*** on the *Sphere Layer* to 1 (it should only take a couple of seconds to render):

[image]

---

4.) After that, blur it as you were with the Environment pass:

[image]

***EDIT:*** I forgot... the reason this works is because you now have a shader (albeit a perfectly clear shader) covering the camera plane.  Blender must render the shader and all the rays that are affecting it, hence the environment on the other side of the glass must be visible.  For obvious reasons, a Transparent shader will not work for this.

Comment: without adding extra geometry you can just add an empty render layer (one that does not contain objects) with the environment pass enabled, so that there is no masking. https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAgtK.png

Comment: @cegaton - You sexy devil.  Why do I even answer when we have you around?

Comment: it's all good. I just like to share ideas. A lot of the times I get it all wrong... Like most of us, I'm just here to learn and share.

Comment: @cegaton - lol, you post and I'll just delete mine.

Comment: don't delete anything. We all come with different solutions. None is more  or less valid.

Answer (score 6):

As [clearly explained by @bertmoog](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/89146/1853) the envirionment pass is missing information.

As an alternative without adding extra geometry, you can just add an empty render layer (one that does not contain objects) with the environment pass enabled, so that there is no masking, blur it and use Alpha Over to composite other elements.

[image]