# How to add motion blur to HDRI backplate? (example included)

Tags: compositing-nodes, motion-capture, hdri

I want to show motion like shown below but keep the far background sharp.

[image]

As you can see above, the wheels and the road, along with the vegetation, are motion blurred but the background, with mountains and sea, is sharp. This whole image, except the car, is a backplate from HDRIhaven. And I have no clue on how to achieve this specific effect.

Comment: I have seen a well documented tutorial on ***exactly*** this effect on the net, but I can't find it. Basically, lowpoly model the environment, keyframe the camera (to create movement), then render a frame of the environment with a Vector pass. Use that vector pass to create vector blur in the compositor on the hdri.

Comment: For a still shot you could also use *Directional Blur* in Compositor

Comment: I would love to see that compositor node layout blurring only a specific areas of the HDRI and not affecting the foreground model.

Comment: To do that in the compositor enable Film-Transparent, the enable the Environment pass.(see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48240/how-to-make-hdri-map-more-subtle/48265#48265) To create this particular effect you would need to blur the background using different overlapping masks with different degrees of Directional blur. But in reality this is better done creating geometry and textures and creating proper motion blur, as the amount of blur is determined by many factors: the speed of the camera and objects, the distance to the camera, lens field of view and shutter speed.