How can an empty object as an image be rendered with the same settings as the rest of the scene?
I'm trying to render an image empty as a backdrop in a scene. When I enabled the focal settings in the camera tab, the physical objects rendered correctly to the focal length but the backdrop is entirely in focus regardless of setting adjustments. Is there a workaround for this issue if so, what can be done about it?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/202278/how-do-i-make-the-cameras-depth-of-field-affect-an-imported-image (also here: does your image have alpha? and here)
